# Why do I get an error about 'unsupported operand types for /'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This program is supposed to check whether an entered number is a prime number.

```
def checkPrime():
    primeASK = raw_input('''Please enter a prime number.''')
    print 'Your Number is %s.' %(primeASK)

    if primeASK.isdigit():
        primeASK = int(primeASK)
        number = 1

        while primeASK > number:
            print primeASK / number

            number += 1 


checkPrime()
```

Here is the error I keep receiving (obviously the program isn't complete)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Lib/idlelib/primeChecker.py", line 14, in <module>
    checkPrime()
  File "C:/Python27/Lib/idlelib/primeChecker.py", line 5, in checkPrime
    if primeASK.isdigit():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Comment: `number + 1  ` it should be `number += 1`

Comment: Now i'm receiving this error... AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: Same Error I just forgot to change it in the question. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry but same error. I'm very new to python, thanks for all of your help but unfortunately I still have the error

Comment: check that raw_input('''Please enter a prime number.''') has not `int()` around it.

Comment: Thank You success! Just had to loof closer at your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to divide a string by an integer, so, you need to parse your input to `int` first.

```
def checkPrime():
    primeASK = raw_input('''Please enter a prime number.''')
    print 'Your Number is %s.' %(primeASK)

    if primeASK.isdigit():
        primeASK = int(primeASK)
        number = 1
```

Also, `number + 1` it should be `number += 1`

Answer (score 2):

`primeAsk` is a String because that's what `raw_input()` returns. Your error is that you are dividing a String by an Integer.